# How to save the state of an object in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Cant change a field value permanently in my windows forms app.

Forgive me if this is something answered somewhere else. I did look and didn't find anything specific. I am trying to design a small game in a windows form app. However an issue I am having is when I change the value of a field in a button event it doesn't permanently apply the change. So when i click on the button again it does not reduce monster hp to 8 it simply repeats the code as if it was the first time executing it. Iv tried using static and ref variables but perhaps I am using them wrong.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PlayerHealth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void MonsterHealth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AttackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player player = new Player();
            Monster monster = new Monster();

            player.AttackMonster(player, monster);
            MonsterHealth.Text = monster.HP.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Player
    {
        public int HP { get; set; }
        public int Attack = 1;

        public void AttackMonster(Player player, Monster monster)
        {
           monster.HP -= player.Attack;

        }
    }

    public class Monster
    {
        public int HP = 10;
        public int Attack { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I am aiming to get the HP field to reduce by one each time the button is clicked. This is not whats happens as of now.

Comment: `new` means *new*

Comment: How many monsters do you intend to have?

Answer (score 3):

HP variable is not decrementing, because you are creating *new instance* of Monster class in every `AttackBtn_Click ()`.

To avoid it create a class level property of Monster instance and instantiate it at class level and use it in `AttackBtn_Click()`function

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Monster MonsterInstance { get; private set; } = new Monster();
    public Player PlayerInstance { get; private set; } = new Player(); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Your business logic

    private void AttackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerInstance.AttackMonster(PlayerInstance, MonsterInstance);
        MonsterHealth.Text = MonsterInstance.HP.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: With that design, `set` might not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Ill give it a shot!

Comment: @AnthonyAbdo you have only 1 Monster in your game?

Comment: No ideally id have more.

Comment: @Phil1970, I updated my answer with `private set`